# Rewording code for better structure

Tags: pascal

```
program GameMain;
uses SwinGame, sgTypes; 

function buttonClicked(p1, Next_PARAM_thingie: Single; W, lastOne: Integer): Boolean; 
var blah, blee: Single; _r_, BTMOB: Single; 
begin blah := MouseX(); blee := MouseY(); _r_ := p1 + W; BTMOB := Next_PARAM_thingie + lastOne; result := false; 
    if MouseClicked( LeftButton ) then 
    begin 
        if (blah >= p1) and (blah <= _r_) then 
        begin result := true; 
        end; 
    end; 
end;

procedure Main();
var
  clr: Color;
begin
  OpenGraphicsWindow('Test Program for Button Click Code', 800, 600); 
  ShowSwinGameSplashScreen(); 
  clr := ColorWhite;

  repeat 
    clearScreen(clr); 
    drawframerate(0,0);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    fillRectangle(ColorGrey, 50, 50, 100, 30); 
    drawtext('Click Me', ColorBlack, 'arial.ttf', 14, 55, 55);

    RefreshScreen(); 
    Processevents();

    if buttonClicked(50, 50, 100, 30) then 
    begin 
      clr := RandomRGBcolor(255);
    end;  
until WindowCloseRequested();
end;

begin 
   main(); 
end.
```

I have been trying to figure out what does what but it isn't going to well. I could use some help trying to figure out what each of these random words do so I can change the name so the code is more understanding

Comment: How do you learn if you delegate all your homework to others. Start with formatting the code properly. Then think yourself, and ask your tutor if they didn't tell you what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I would do is work through removing things that are unneeded.  In the code sample given, BTMOB is entirely unused, so I would remove it and the code that sets its value.  With BTMOB removed, the lastOne parameter is no longer needed, so it goes away.

Keep chipping away things that don't belong at all and using whatever context clues are available to give things that are used more meaningful names.  There will be some things that you may not be able to guess just by analyzing the code and potentially not even through runtime debugging, but you should be able to make it *far* more readable.  Here's an example of how buttonClicked might look after the first pass (you'd also have to change the code that calls it to no longer pass the unused parameters that were removed).

```
function buttonClicked(p1: Single; W: Integer): Boolean; 
    var posX: Single; _r_: Single; 
    begin posX := MouseX(); _r_ := p1 + W; result := false; 
        if MouseClicked( LeftButton ) then 
        begin 
            if (posX >= p1) and (posX <= _r_) then 
                begin result := true; 
        end; 
    end; 
end;
```